# Where is the {{welcome-page}} data coming from in Ember?

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-cli

I am new to Ember, after I installed ember, I am seeing default welcome-page which is via application.hbs. Can someone please tell me where this data of welcome-page resides? Where is that being pulled from? I want to go through the code. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

The welcome page is an 'add-on' that is included in fresh Ember installs by default. In Ember, [add-ons](https://guides.emberjs.com/v3.0.0/tutorial/installing-addons/) are stored in the `node_modules` folder in the root of your project. You install them with `ember install add-on-name` but under the hood, it's using [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/).

Here is the repository for the source: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-welcome-page.

Specifically, the template is here: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-welcome-page/blob/master/addon/templates/components/welcome-page.hbs in the add-on's 'addon' folder... and that is also pulling in images etc from other places.

If you wish to start a project / and skip the welcome page addition - *as of 2.14*, you have this flag available:

`ember new my-project --no-welcome`

PS: Add-on file structures are whacky and confusing (to me) - you might want to start with another entry point if you are new to Ember. [Here is an example](https://ember-twiddle.com/9582b3fb1bacd111295654a34b54912e?openFiles=templates.application.hbs%2Ctemplates.components.example-component.hbs) of how a component(very similar to the welcome page) works / outside of the mysterious addon world.

The welcome page is confusing in general. You might find this person's experience interesting: https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-welcome-page/issues/81

Answer (score 0):

It should be installed in your node_modules folder. You can find the source code here(https://github.com/ember-cli/ember-welcome-page).